# How to stub static class methods through rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a static method which initiates a static variable by making a external service call. I want to stub that static method call so that external service call is not made while initializing of the class variable.
here is an example of my code in simple terms.

```
class ABC
    def self.ini
        return someCallToMyExternalLibrary # i don't want the execution to go there while testing
    end

    @@config = self.ini

    def method1
        return @@config['download_URL']
    end
end
```

Now I want to stub the static method call with my object so that @@config is initialized with the response which I want to get.
I have tried several things and I seems that @@config is not initialized with my object but by the implemented call only.

```
describe ABC do
    let(:myObject) { Util.jsonFromFile("/data/app_config.json")}
    let(:ABC_instance) { ABC.new }

    before(:each) do
        ABC.stub(:ini).and_return(myObject)
    end

    it "check the download url" do
        ABC_instance.method1.should eql("download_url_test")
        # this test fails as @@config is not getting initialized with my object
        # it returns the download url as per the implementation.
    end

end
```

I have even tried stubing in the spec_helper with the though that it will be executed first before the class variable is initialized when execution reaches there, but that also did not help. I am stuck with this now for a while. Someone please be a Savior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the initialization of `@@config` is occurring while the class `ABC` is being loaded and there is no way for you intervene in that process via stubbing. If you cannot stub the external call itself, then the only thing I can think of is to change the class definition to include a separate class initialization method.

Comment: thanks peter, I also kind of figured that out the hard way !!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of stubbing the ":ini" method, which I suppose that you cannot do because the parser goes through the ABC definition before your call to stub the method, I would suggest that you set the class variable @@config to the value you want on your before block:

```
before(:each) do
  ABC.class_variable_set(:@@config, myObject)
end
```

Then try to see whether this solves your problem.

Comment: I have already tried this as well, but still not getting my desired respone, it seems that parser is reading ABC.class_variable_set(:@@config, myObject) post parsing the class ABC. Is there a way to parse ABC.class_variable_set(:@@config, myObject) first and set the class varaible ?

Comment: Try this one: Remove the let on :ABC_instance...and put inside your test "ABC_instance = ABC.new". Does this make any difference?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you further. I have written a sample project on my own and it works for me. I have published the code here: https://github.com/pmatsinopoulos/test_stub_on_class

Comment: can this be related to Rspec-rails version, i am using rails 3.2 ruby 1.9  and rspec-rails 2.6

Comment: It may be so. My example is with rspec 2.14. Maybe, you can try an upgrade to latest rspec